# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, потоки-данных, сериализация

Вначале записываю в конец файла(запускаю 2 раза):

```
File file= new File("src\\file.dat");
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
try{
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(new Object());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Потом читаю из файла:

```
File file = new File("src\\file.dat");
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
try{
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    System.out.println(inputStream.readObject());
    System.out.println(inputStream.readObject());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Выкидывает ошибку:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1563)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:32)

Comment: не надо запускать два раза, `ObjectOutputStream` при создании пишет в поток служебный заголовок, на котором потом спотыкается `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("src\\file.dat");
        write(file);
        System.out.println(read(file));
        System.out.println(read(file));

    }

    public static boolean write(File file) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true))) {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(new Object());
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Object read(File file) {
        try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));) {
            return inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так. Вся суть в использовании trywithresources и метода flush. Информации про это добро навалом. И напоследок рекомендация - используйте буферизацию для стримов. Про BufferedStream также инфы навалом.